# A word to describe the completion of uncompleted work before a vacation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

> Backlog/noun
>
> - an accumulation of uncompleted work waiting for you when you return from vacation .

It's a pity that we don't have "[forelog](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/4488/Forelog)" as a word for **work that is done to clear one's desk before a vacation.**

- What are the some alternatives to define all the work that is done to
  clear one's desk before a vacation?

Comment: I thinks that's also backlog. I never thought that backlog is limited to post-vacation accumulation. It's used more generally for work that piled up waiting to be done.

Comment: Ironically, "backlog" originally meant something similar to what you're seeking, as it referred to the big log behind the fire, ready to burn, to be used later, not to unfinished work.

Comment: I think _backlog_ more generally refers to anything that accumulates because new items arrive faster than they can be consumed. Vacations are just an extreme case because nothing gets done while you're away. But you can have a backlog any time you can't keep up with the incoming tasks.

Comment: Post-vacation backlog.  Kinda has a nice ring to it, doesn't it? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a single word, but I've often heard it referred to as *cleaning one's plate*.

Comment: or "cleaning the slate".

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain that there is a single word or phrase that is adequate to describe what I consider to be **a process**.  Before you leave for the day, you do certain things, depending upon the job.  Before you leave for vacation, you do the same things you would do when leaving for the day, plus a few more.

In most cases, these are not limited to a desk, a cubicle, or an office.  They involve communication with other staff, so that things run smoothly while you are away.  If you need temporary workplace help to do your job while you are away, then you need to hire, train, or at the very least instruct them in your work and in workplace procedures, so they are not lost and end up adding more work for you and everyone else.

If you don't need to hire or bring in temporary people, you still need to delegate responsibilities, so that things get done in a timely fashion while you are not there to monitor them.

I suppose it really depends on the job, the environment, and your position within that environment.  If you're the boss, finishing your current work is not enough, but if you're one of a half-dozen receptionists, it may be.

Check out Time Management Ninja's post on the [Ten Tasks to Do Before Leaving on a Break](http://timemanagementninja.com/2012/07/10-tasks-to-do-before-leaving-on-a-break/).  It doesn't necessarily give you the proper word to use to describe what you want, but it does discuss the process in detail -- and that might give you the words you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> "It's a pity that we don't have "forelog" as a word for work that is done to clear one's desk before a vacation. What are the some alternatives to define all the work that is done to clear one's desk before a vacation.

Forelog is not a word, it was suggested to and [rejected by the Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/4488/Forelog). There is a real antonym: "[forestick](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/forestick)".

The [Online Entomology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/) describes the derivative and usage of "[backlog](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backlog)" as:

> **[backlog](https://www.etymonline.com/word/backlog) (n.)**
> also back-log, 1680s, "large log placed at the back of a fire" to keep the blaze going and concentrate the heat; see [back](https://www.etymonline.com/word/back?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_28954) (adj.) + [log](https://www.etymonline.com/word/log?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_12387) (n.1). Figurative sense of "something stored up for later use" is first attested 1883, but this and the meaning "arrears of unfulfilled orders" (1932) might be from, or suggested by, [log](https://www.etymonline.com/word/log?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_43590) (n.2).

See also: [What does log in "backlog" refer to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/340021/246019)

The antonyms for [backlog](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/backlog) or [excess](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/excess) offer no assistance to derive a good word, the reference to the entomology of "backlog" is lost and no reference to tasks to be completed in the short-term is found. We must ***stick*** with the fireplace modernism and it's terminology to find the needed word.

A lesser known word is "[forestick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forestick)" (also referenced by [rajah9](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3306/rajah9) in their [comment on their answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340021/what-does-log-in-backlog-refer-to#comment783247_340113)):

> **forestick (n.)** (plural foresticks)
> The front stick of a fire in a [hearth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hearth).
>  
> Word origin
> [1785–95, Amer.; fore- + stick]

Usage [examples](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/forestick) from Dictionary.com:

> **Example sentences from the Web for "forestick":**
>  
> Before the forestick had burned in two, she heard him coming, but he was not alone.
> Country Neighbors | Alice Brown
>  
>  
> On a fire well started thus between backlog and forestick he may pile such dry, hard wood as he has at hand.
> Old Plymouth Trails | Winthrop Packard
>  
>  
> The bright flame on the forestick, which Ralph had been watching, flickered and burned low.
> The Hoosier Schoolmaster | Edward Eggleston
>  
>  
> So you jist let me put on a good back-log and forestick, and build up a fire to tell stories by this evening.
> The Pearl of Orr's Island | Harriet Beecher Stowe

I suggest that "forestick" has an equal footing, within the same sub-space, and is a good antonym for backlog; to refer to something stuck before you that is smaller than a log and needs to be started before other tasks can be undertaken.